# Django - There is a way to get the current database alias?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working in a django project with multiple databases and I'm searching a way to get the current database alias using an import or method.

I've been searching in the documentation, but I haven't find any useful information.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a QuerySet you can retrieve the db name using the [db property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.db):

```
>>> f = Item.objects.all()
>>> f.db
'default'
```

If you have the model instance (you evaluated the QuerySet), you can query the [ModelState](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/db/models/base.py#L373) (Note that this is not documented, so it could change in the future and not recommended to use in apps as @Weier said):

```
>>> f = Item.objects.all()[4]
>>> f._state.db
'default'
```

Comment: It would be better not to provide a link to the code implementation as a reference. Anything not mentioned in Django documentation should be considered a private API and not be used in Django applications.

Comment: You are right, QuerySet.db is documented while ModelState no. Editing

Answer (score 3):

There is not exactly such thing as 'current' db alias in Django.

Have a look at the docs for db routers to understand why:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers

(though @fasouto does correctly show 'current' alias, in context of a read operation on a particular model, by using private API of `QuerySet`)

try this:

```
from django.db import router

alias_for_read = router.db_for_read(MyModelClass)
# optionally:
alias_for_read = router.db_for_read(MyModelClass, instance=my_model_instance)

# similarly:
alias_for_write = router.db_for_write(MyModelClass)
alias_for_write = router.db_for_write(MyModelClass, instance=my_model_instance)
```

Regarding the `instance` parameter... spec for db router classes says that they should accept `**hints` kwargs. They also state that only supported hint currently is `instance`. But unless you have a custom router class that makes use of this hint you will not need to supply the current instance.